# How to evaluate {Subscript[x, 1] == 2, Subscript[x, 2] == 3} , $x_1^2+x_2=2^2+3=7$

Tags: list-manipulation

My code simply can't solve this. $ x_1^2 + x_2 = 2^2 + 3 = 7 $

```
assign[eqn_] := 
 Thread[Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[Length[Solve[eqn, x]]] ==
   Values@Flatten@Solve[eqn, x]];
assign[x^2 - 5 x == -6]
```

Output

```
{Subscript[x, 1] == 2, Subscript[x, 2] == 3}
```

But then when I input

```
Subscript[x, 1 ]^2 + Subscript[x, 2]
```

***It just simply output what I've input.***

Comment: Maybe give Mathematica a bit more guidance:  `Simplify[ Subscript[x, 1]^2 + Subscript[x, 2],  Assumptions -> assign[ x^2 - 5 x == -6 ] ] `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Note that [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) (`==`) does not assign values. You need to use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`)

```
assign[eqn_] := 
  Thread[Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[Length[Solve[eqn, x]]] == 
     Values@Flatten@Solve[eqn, x]] /. Equal -> Set;

assign[x^2 - 5 x == -6]

(* {2, 3} *)

Subscript[x, 1]^2 + Subscript[x, 2]

(* 7 *)
```

Comment: This is a great trick!  Somehow in my 16 years of mathematica use I've never seen the `./ Equal -> Set` rule.